# How to manage Docker private registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I've set up Docker and running a private repository on `example.com:5000`. I followed the instructions listed here: https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/

And uses the docker-compose.yml:

```
registry:
  restart: always
  image: registry:2
  ports:
    - 5000:5000
  environment:
    REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE: /certs/domain.crt
    REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY: /certs/domain.key
    REGISTRY_AUTH: htpasswd
    REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH: /auth/htpasswd
    REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM: Registry Realm
  volumes:
    - /path/data:/var/lib/registry
    - /path/certs:/certs
    - /path/auth:/auth
```

I can **push** and **pull** images to the repository, but I can't get `docker search example.com:5000/library` to run. I get an: `Error response from daemon: Unexpected status code 404`.

When I point curl to the endpoint I get the following result:

```
$ curl -v -X GET http://example.com:5000/v2/images
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying 37.139.20.160...
* Connected to example.com (192.167.201.2) port 5000 (#0)
> GET /v2/images HTTP/1.1
> Host: domain.com:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 

* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
```

How can I make the search command working so that I can manage the repository? And where can I find the API documentation of the endpoint? Or are there better ways to manage a Docker private repo?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to activate the search option, according to [Search-engine options](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry#search-engine-options)

> The Docker Registry can optionally index repository information in a database for the `GET /v1/search` endpoint.

(I don't see a search in the [V2 API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#detail). You can [list tags](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#listing-image-tags))

> The `search_backend` setting selects the search backend to use.
>   If `search_backend` is empty, no index is built, and the search endpoint always returns empty results.

For instance, using the [SQLAlchemy database](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/)

```
common:
  search_backend: sqlalchemy
  sqlalchemy_index_database: sqlite:////tmp/docker-registry.db
```

> On initialization, the SQLAlchemyIndex class checks the database version. If the database doesn't exist yet (or does exist, but lacks a version table), the SQLAlchemyIndex creates the database and required tables.